# Process HTML file using Thymeleaf in Web based Scopes of Spring and store the processed template as String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to render an HTML file using thymeleaf and keep the resultant HTML content in a String variable in `web-based scopes of Spring` so that i can use it later for sending email or converting the content to pdf. I have gone through the implementation given in [this](https://tuhrig.de/generating-pdfs-with-java-flying-saucer-and-thymeleaf/) website but its giving me error which i couldn't figure out. I am using spring boot 1.5.12.RELEASE with thymeleaf 3.0.9 n thymeleaf dialect 2.2.2. Below is my implementation. Please help.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Controller
public class jataController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/manual-thym")
    @ResponseBody
    public void justSample() {
        Context context = new Context();
        String filename = "templates/view/failure";
        String html = renderHtml(filename, context);
        System.out.println("template\n" + html);
    }

    private String renderHtml(String filename, Context context) {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        String html = templateEngine.process(filename, context);

        return html;
    }
}
```

And the StackTrace:

```
2018-04-19 12:26:43.742 ERROR 6375 --- [nio-9000-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ognl/PropertyAccessor] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ognl.PropertyAccessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.<init>(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:83) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.getVariableExpressionEvaluator(StandardDialect.java:179) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.StandardDialect.getExecutionAttributes(StandardDialect.java:393) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.DialectSetConfiguration.build(DialectSetConfiguration.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.EngineConfiguration.<init>(EngineConfiguration.java:123) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.initialize(TemplateEngine.java:336) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1079) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.siqes.flight.controller.jataController.renderHtml(jataController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.siqes.flight.controller.jataController.justSample(jataController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See update below

When you configure Thymeleaf you should define the template engine and the template resolver otherwise when you autowire defaults are used. If you create an instance every time it is not a good practice. Here a sample configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver 
          = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to experiment programmatically you can autowire them but the usual flow for serving html pages with thymeleaf is to define the view resolver as well:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return viewResolver;
}
```

With all that in place you can write a controller as:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return "yourTemplateName";
    }
}
```

Parameters can be passed to the template by using model attributes.

**UPDATE 31/07/2018**

unfortunately I do not have the time to complete working proof of concept, however I think the below code is enough to show the flow. If you run it and call `localhost:8080/test` you should be able to see the output html in the console. The pdf generation can be added as a view resolver and/or invoked programmatically, in this example using `xhtmlrenderer`; I do not have the time to complete it so I commented it out but you can get the point: a service provide the html and pdf generation by autowiring the template engine.

[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.paizo</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>html2pdf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

ThymeleafConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private Html2PdfService pdfService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public String hello() {
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("name", "Borat");
        System.out.println(pdfService.template2Html("test", parameters));
        return "test";
    }

//    @ResponseBody
//    @GetMapping
//    public ResponseEntity helloPdf() {
//        Map parameters = new HashMap();
//        parameters.put("name", "Borat");
//        pdfService.template2Pdf("test", parameters);
//        String filePath = "PATH_HERE";
//        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
//        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
//        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//        headers.setContentLength();
//        return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
//    }
}
```

Html2PdfService.java

```
@Service
public class Html2PdfService {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public OutputStream template2Pdf(String templateName, Map parameters) {
//        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream();
//        IOUtils.copy()
//
//        Context ctx = new Context();
//        String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
//        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
//        renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml);
//        renderer.layout();
//        renderer.createPDF(os, false);
//        renderer.finishPDF();
        return null;
    }

    public String template2Html(String templateName, Map parameters) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariable("name", "pippo");
        String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
        return processedHtml;
    }
}
```

Html2pdfApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Html2pdfApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Html2pdfApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

as a side note if you plan to generate the pdf on the fly and serve it as response in the controller I suggest to use streams and not byte arrays or temp files.

Comment: Hello @Paizo would you like to review my answer so that i can give you the bounty

Comment: Hi @SAM I just updated the answer with a working example a bit more clean for the html part rather than going point to point on your code; i'm not sure about the leak you mention, it might be related to the mix of annotations all defined in the controller class

Comment: Yes i use ByteArrayInputStream avoiding temp files.

Comment: Thank you devoting some of your valuable time. I am able to process the template and generate pdf using itext. i believe flyingsaucer also uses itext. but the problem is with the scope of the beans. If i switch to web based scopes like request, session, globalSession i get exceptions. but using the thymeleaf configuration described beans for template processing doesn't have any issue with application scope in that. and that happeded when annotate a class with configuration and controller which i feel it as a bad practice. any solution on how to refactor my codes.

Comment: yes see mine :D provide the functionality with a `@Service` (default to singleton), do not create manually instances of `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` just the define the beans in a `@Configuration` class and autowire them in the service, should provide you just 1 instance of the beans regardless of the requests. do not mix multiple class annotations, `@EnableWebMvc` is not needed. The service give you an abstract layer that allows you can easily change the implementation. If you can pass the pdf stream directly from itext->service->controller is better performance and memory saved

Comment: I understand your implementation but my requirement web based scopes with other beans having request scopes and manually processing of template with thymeleaf in a Application scope. But my controller got mixed up with configuration and that is where i believe is the bad practice. No doubt it is working flawless but it hasbad practice

Comment: Thank you for devoting some time, but i wanted to remove the bad practice from my code too. If you can then please look into this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636312/annotated-a-class-with-configuration-and-controller-is-it-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

If `TemplateEngine` is autowired inside a `singleton` bean, then the below mentioned code works perfect.

```
@Controller
public class jataController {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @GetMapping(value = "/manual-thym")
    @ResponseBody
    public void justSample() {
        Context context = new Context();
        String filename = "templates/view/generated-ticket.html";
        String html = renderHtml(filename, context);
        System.out.println("template\n" + html);
    }

    private String renderHtml(String filename, Context context) {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        String html = templateEngine.process(filename, context);

        return html;
    }
}
```

but if `TemplateEngine` is autowired on a `request` scope bean type, it gives exception and `thymeleaf` will create a memory leak. So finally with lots of hit and tries, i got a working solution and thanks to @Paizo. It might contain some bad practice but this is how it worked:

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ApplicationScope
public class MyThymeleafConfig {

    @GetMapping("/view-template")
    @ResponseBody
    public void viewTemplates() {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("mydata", "this is it");

        String html = templateEngine().process("templates/view-to-process.html", context);
        System.out.println(html);
    }


    /*

    configuration for thymeleaf and template processing

    */

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

and to serve the static resources we need to define another bean, which is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/", "classpath:static/");
    }
}
```

This solution cannot be found on any forum. However i would ask as well as request any `Spring` developer to **provide a better implementation** for the above code.

Comment: because it is using the default @Bean for it with standard configuration, before you where creating a new instance without configuration. Also why are you converting the template by hand and return it in the controller?

Comment: i want to process the html page with thymeleaf and then store it in a string variable so that i can use it for html to pdf conversion.

Comment: That means autowiring takes default configuration of spring default beans.

Comment: Why not just persist content in a Redis for example?

Comment: What should i persist in redis

Answer (score 2):

I'm using similar Springboot and Thymeleaf versions and something like this worked for me on a few projects :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;

@Component
public class EmailProcessor {

    private TemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine;

    @Autowired
    public EmailProcessor(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.htmlTemplateEngine = templateEngine;
    }


    public String process(User user) {

        final Context ctx = new Context();

        if (user != null) {
            ctx.setVariable("user", user);
        }

        return htmlTemplateEngine.process("emails/template", ctx);
    }
}
```

Email template is just a regular Thymeleaf template which is located in:

> resouces/templates/emails/template.html

Comment: this has worked for me too when the bean type is 'singleton'. but when the bean type is 'request' it will give you error. try it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Maven, add ognl dependency to your pom.xml file, e.g. (find the latest dependency/version in [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ognl/ognl)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ognl</groupId>
    <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my html template was not in right directory. Changed that to "src/main/resources/abc.html" and this fixed my error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ognl.PropertyAccessor
```