# Annotated a class with @Configuration and @Controller. Need help in refactoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Below is my class in which i had to use both `@Configuration` and `@Controller` as there should be only one instance of `Thymeleaf` in the entire application else i get exceptions for that. My other classes are annotated with `@RequestScope` so i cannot use a singleton scoped bean. So i had a mixup of Configuration and Controller to get the result, but i feel it is a bad practice. I would appreciate any help to refactor the code and remove the bad practice.

**UPDATE**

I am using `spring-boot 1.5.14`. I am using the following approach to process a template and keep the processed template as string.

```
@Controller
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ApplicationScope
public class MyThymeleafConfig {

    @GetMapping("/view-template")
    @ResponseBody
    public void viewTemplates() {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("mydata", "this is it");

        String html = templateEngine().process("templates/view-to-process.html", context);
        System.out.println(html);
    }


    /*

    configuration for thymeleaf and template processing

    */

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

To serve static resources the following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/", "classpath:static/");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have also mentioned the reasons why i couldn't accept the below mentioned answers as my other classes have request scopes.

**UPDATE**

I have other classes with `@RequestScope`like below:

```
@RequestScope
@Controller
public class SecondController {

    @GetMapping("/viewPage")
    public String viewPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mydata", "sjfbsdf");
        model.addAttribute("somedata", "sjdfksfjhshgdfbskdfj");
        return "templates/view-to-process.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would not do this as I like to keep concerns separated as much as possible.  Create a class for this one controller method, (maybe ViewController) scope it how you want and add your RequestMapping there.  Thus you've separated config from controller.

Comment: But that is not possible here, as there can be only one instance of thymeleaf in the entire application. Please help me refactoring the codes.

Comment: i will also give bounty to whoever refactors the above code with rest of the controllers annotated with request scope.

Comment: Some body please try all your respective answers with requestb scoped beans as well. I am waiting to give the bounty.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using Spring Boot, since you have it in tags, you do not need any configuration to use Thymeleaf.

By just having [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf), you can:

```
@GetMapping("/view-template")
public String viewTemplates(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("mydata", "this is it")
    return "view-to-process";
}
```

And it should work.

By the way, yes, having `@Configuration` and `@Controller` in the same class is something you should never need.

Comment: Thank u for your time. actually i forgot to add the reason why i did this, but i have now updated the question.

Comment: @SAM, Please consider to accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @Michael : I have followed the above approach but it works if i only process template and keep the resultant as string and then i cannot view any pages with thymeleaf and so i had use an approach which is actually a bad practice. If i get some help in refactoring the code and remove the bad practice.

Answer (score 6):

If you see the source codes of the annotations (Spring 5) you have:

#### Controller

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller {

    /**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any (or empty String otherwise)
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class)
    String value() default "";

}
```

#### Configuration

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Configuration {

    /**
     * Explicitly specify the name of the Spring bean definition associated
     * with this Configuration class. If left unspecified (the common case),
     * a bean name will be automatically generated.
     * <p>The custom name applies only if the Configuration class is picked up via
     * component scanning or supplied directly to a {@link AnnotationConfigApplicationContext}.
     * If the Configuration class is registered as a traditional XML bean definition,
     * the name/id of the bean element will take precedence.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any (or empty String otherwise)
     * @see org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultBeanNameGenerator
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class)
    String value() default "";
}
```

you notice that they are the same (they both include the more generic `@Component` annotation). So it doesn't make sense to use them both by seeing this fact. Another thing, more important, is that spring is trying to give a sort of *tags* meaning of these annotations that should describe the use.

The `Configuration` is used to **wire in** necessary parts to the application to function properly, at startup phase.

The `Controller` is used to define a class which is serving as an interface to the outside world, i.e: how can other actors use your application.

As you can see, it makes very little sense to use those 2 together.

Comment: If i donot use `@Configuration` then i get an exception that Application context cannot be null and if i donot use `@Controller` then my mapping aren't found giving me 404.

Comment: This is wrong. `@Configuration` also have influence on beans creation, it's not the same as `@Controller`

Comment: @Mahn That's from processing point of view. I explained that they are the same strictly talking about code, but then I specified that they have different usages. Read completely before making conclusions.

Answer (score 5):

Take look at Spring Boot documentation [typical layout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

Also this article [SOLID Programming Principles](https://springframework.guru/solid-principles-object-oriented-programming/)

And look at Spring Boot guide [Spring Boot Thymeleaf](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) (you don't need your @Bean configurations)

In two words you should separate
 1. `MyThymeleafConfig` configuration
 2. `TemplateController` with `viewTemplates()` and another endpoints

Comment: I know i must do that, but i didn't had any choice as there can be only one instance of thymeleaf in the entire application. So i asked for some help in refactoring the above codes.

Comment: What do you mean 'one instance of thymeleaf' ? do you mean how to use `templateEngine()` in `Controller` from `MyThymeleafConfig` ? you can autowire any bean defined with `@Bean` annotation, in your case its - `@Autowired SpringTemplateEngine`

Comment: In case of thymeleaf, there can be only one instance in an application. Try it yourself.

Comment: Yes, you have one instance, and when you `@Autowired` you also have one instance - its singleton :) you don't need many instances for thymeleaf

Comment: also, I agree with @sedooe approach, its also what you need - keep the processed template as string

Comment: Please try sedooe s approach by processing a template and keeping it as string, and then view a different web page. You will definitely get an exception

Comment: please provide example or vore details

Comment: sure. I have posted an answer in the following thread. i have mentioned both 2 different styles to achieve one of which is here. you will definitely encounter the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914891/process-html-file-using-thymeleaf-in-web-based-scopes-of-spring-and-store-the-pr

Answer (score 5):

To refactor them, it's easy and straight forward to separate `@Bean` methods to a separate `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
// @Controller  is redundant as we have @Configuration
// @EnableWebMvc is also redundant since you already annotate it in other class
// @ApplicationScope is also redundant since you do not need to create bean of MyThymeleafConfig anymore
public class MyThymeleafConfig {
    /*

    configuration for thymeleaf and template processing

    */

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

`@Configuration` class return the same bean instance, regardless how many times you call the bean methods.

Now in your controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyThymeleafConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @GetMapping("/view-template")
    @ResponseBody
    public void viewTemplates() {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("mydata", "this is it");

        String html = templateEngine.process("templates/view-to-process.html", context);
        System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

But honestly, I don't know why you have to manually interact with TemplateEngine / SpringTemplateEngine, since Spring-thymeleaf will automatically process the template with given variable for you. (Like @sedooe example)

Comment: I have tried the above codes but my other codes are having request scopes and so i get error

Comment: Which one? `@RequestScoped` can be accessed in a singleton bean and vice versa. I see no problem here. You should post your other code and your error for detail help.

Comment: I think you may trying to access a `@RequestScoped` bean outside of a request, otherwise, there should be no problem. Anyway, a sample code would help

Answer (score 3):

Don't put request mappings inside configuration classes, it violates the principal of  separation of concerns. You can go for a approach like below.

All the application wide beans are setup in `Application` class which is present in the root of the classpath. `Application` class in the best place to have your **thymeleaf** and **static resource** configurations too, since the `Application` class have application-scope.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
       ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
       resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
       resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       resolver.setCache(false);
       return resolver;
    }

   @Bean
   public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
   }

   private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
       SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new 
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
       resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
       resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
       return resolver;
   }
}
```

If you put the static resources inside a folder named **static** or **public** in the classpath, springboot identify that as the location for static resources. Then you don't need to override `addResourceHandlers` method. If you really want to do it, you can do it inside the Application class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. You don't need separate class to configure just static resource paths.

Don't put request mappings inside configuration classes, put them in separate controller classes like:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @GetMapping("/view-template")
   @ResponseBody
   public void viewTemplates() {
         Context context = new Context();
         context.setVariable("mydata", "this is it");

         String html = templateEngine().process("templates/view-to-process.html", context);
         System.out.println(html);
    }
}
```

Of cause, springboot allows you to do it the way you like, but you'd better stick to a general approach.

Comment: I know it is violating the separation of concerns principal but i didn't had any other option. I have tried the above code many time but it doesn't solve my problem s my other beans are of request scope.

Comment: Can you please explain how your other beans being @RequestScope (which seems suspect to me) cause an issue with the above solution? You still have a single TemplateEngine bean defined in the application scope. You can then autowire it into your request scope classes as needed...

Answer (score 0):

These two annotations are for different things, thus it's better to not use them on the same class. Cause it's against  [`Separation of Concerns`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principal.

Comment: I admit its violating the separation of concerns principal but i didn;t had any choice. In any case i use thymeleaf to process a template then, after that i cannot view pages giving me exception that viewresolver can be initiated only once. The same happen if i do the vice versa.